# Netflix access across different countries

Tags: netflix, access-control

Recently, I saw the Netflix multiple users shared account wherein 4 persons can simultaneously stream videos. Some of my friends cam up with an idea to share it, but the problem is that two of them are in India, one is in Germany and one in France (me).

So, does the shared subscription of Netflix have any restriction on the location of the person (in this case)? Or it is purely based on whether one has an account or not regardless of his location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can use the same account in every country.

Only the content which is available differs.

This means:

- You will be able to see only content from France
- Your friend will be able to see only content from Germany
- Your two friends will be able to see only content from India